# Iterator design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator

**Edited for Clarity**

I was following a set of tutorial videos on design patterns that use Java to demonstrate various pattern uses, but when I got to the video titled "The Iterator Design Pattern" it just seemed to use a standard Java iterator.  I have used iterators in Java before, but was never taught them as a "design pattern."  Is there a difference between using an iterator in Java and using the "iterator design pattern"?  If so, what is the distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterators you have used in Java actually implement the [Iterator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern). They do:

> Provide a way to access the elements of an aggregate object sequentially without exposing its underlying representation.  [-Wikipedia Article definition-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern#Definition)

As you can see in the documentation of the [Iterable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) in Java, most of the containers you know supply an Iterator object used to:

> access their elements sequentially without exposing their underlying representation.

Comment: what exactly means **without exposing its underlying representation**, could you please provide a further explanation?

Answer (score 1):

This question is very general with little context, but what they're probably getting at is: there's a difference between using an iterator (something that has a handle to the underlying data and can be moved around the sequence in some way) and using an index (something that tells you how many steps into the sequence you've are) to traverse something sequence-like.

Comment: I'm sure that the garbage collector will come along and dispose of this comment, but @Paul : This answer gave me such a good laugh, I cannot help but point this out, and for what its worth, the "very general", "little context" presents the perfect opportunity to point out the uncomfortable fit that OOP has in the sterile SE philosophy of ASK/ANSWER w/STRICT clarity. Also, the difficulty that the general SO/SE community has in recognizing and negotiating this exception. OOP is, by definition GENERAL, and DECOUPLED, just like this answer, which implements the paradigm, so +1. and thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is **Iterator Pattern** is used to create a custom Iterator for your Custom Collection

In the below example I have created My Custom Collection and Custom Iterator which will iterate in descending Order.

Note - This can be done in Collections.reverseOrder(). Just for illustration I have taken that.

```
package com.designpattern.behavioural.iteratorpattern;

/*
 * Java Iterator Pattern
 * Iterator Pattern allows to access the elements in an Object in a sequential manner rather than exposing the internal logic 
 * Use Case - Traverse on  different way based on the requirement
 */

/*
 * Iterator interface
 */
interface Iterator {

    public boolean hasNext();
    public Object next();

}

/*
 * Repository interface
 */
interface MyCollection {

    public Iterator getIterator();

}

/*
 * Repository and iterator implementation
 * Customized iteration - Iterate in reverse order
 */
class MyCustomCollection implements MyCollection {

    RepositoryIterator iterator = null;

    @Override
    public Iterator getIterator() {
        iterator = new RepositoryIterator();
        return iterator;
    }

    private class RepositoryIterator implements Iterator {

        String[] elements = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

        int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (index < elements.length) {

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            if (this.hasNext()) {
                index += 1;
                return elements[elements.length-index];

            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}

public class IteratorPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyCollection myCollection = new MyCustomCollection();

        for (Iterator iterator = myCollection.getIterator() ; iterator.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

Answer (score 0):

@Kvass by tagging the programming language you may clarify the question. 
If Iterator is an interface and tutorial represent over this interface it is ok!

But some resources mention it slightly .(Inspecting IEnumerable in C# or Iterable generic interface for Java tells us more.Using them ok but not tell us clearly what is going on. We should understand the process for this interfaces to cover iterator design pattern)

If you need this resource good for iterator http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternIterator.aspx#_self1 the data traversed is an indexed property here.

It can be hashed list or something else. The point is obtaining an abstract iterator interface which has first,next,last,currentItem like attributes. by a method such as CreateIterator or GetEnumerator.